# How to hide the y axis except min max in ECharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using Apache ECharts and I don't want to show the labels of the y axis except the min and max.

Here is an screenshot, I want to hide all except 1 and 625:

[image]

Currently, I have this settings for y axis:

```
{
 type: "log",
 min: 1,
 logBase: 5,
}
```

I tried to set "splitNumber" to 1 but the chart is showing 9.8M as max when the expected is 625:
[image]

Comment: I think you can use ```formatter```.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I tried but I don't have the last index, because some times there is 5 or 4 labels.

Comment: Just precompute your expected maximum and set `max`. Also note, that taking away the labels from a log axis decreases the amount of information that can be seen directly. There is no way for the user to know its a log axis.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I agree with you regarding the note, but unfortunately I don't have control over the decision. I will try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Allow me to post an answer so I can explain clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can use `formatter`.

This is just a sample execution that uses a `formatter`.

```
option = {
 yAxis: {
  type: "log",
  min: 1,
  max: 625,
  logBase: 5,
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: function(value, index) {
      // If the value is equal to the min or max, return the value
      if (value === 1 || value === 625) {
        return value;
      }
      // Otherwise, return an empty string to hide the label
      return '';
    }
  }
 }
};option = {
 yAxis: {
  type: "log",
  min: 1,
  max: 625,
  logBase: 5,
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: function(value, index) {
      // If the value is equal to the min or max, return the value
      if (value === 1 || value === 625) {
        return value;
      }
      // Otherwise, return an empty string to hide the label
      return '';
    }
  }
 }
};
```

You see here that I used `formatter` to customize the display of your labels on the y-axis. This function checks if the current value of your label  is equal to the min or max, if true, it returns the value, if false it returns an empty string, so this empty string we use is likely hiding the label, but in reality it show like `""`.

After this, hoping that your chart will looks like this.
[image]